# Show difference between files or objects

Tags: r, diff

Is there a way in R to compare objects and return something useful like where the differences are? I need to compare files, but am willing to read them in to data.frames. This might just be handled better from the command line, but I would like to encapsulate my testing into one R script. My next attempt will be to use ddply to send each line to a compare() function and return the line numbers of the "FALSE" lines, but that only works until you have one insertion or deletion, then everything else becomes "FALSE".

Thanks.

EDIT: the files contain a combination of numeric and character data.

Comment: It will probably help people to know what data types your files or data frames contain. Characters? Integers? Floats? A mixture?

Comment: I am also looking for something similar to the diff, match and patch library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system(paste("fc", <file1>, <file2>, "> difference.txt"))`

seems to work. My Google-fu was off today.

Answer (score 9):

I know it has been a while, but if someone else stumbles on this...

If you are only looking to view the differences, and not use them in code, see the package diffr.

```
install.packages("diffr")
library(diffr)
diffr("file1.txt", "file2.txt", contextSize = 0, minJumpSize = 500)
```

It shows the total contents of both files side by side with differences highlighted in the RStudio Viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Since it sounds like your files are plain text, a command line `diff` tool will work great for this. There is one built-in on mac and unix. Syntax is simply:

```
$ diff <file1> <file2>
```

There are a bunch of others available also, as well as GUI wrappers for different OSes. On Mac, I like [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) and [Delta Walker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx) if you need merge capabilites. On Windows, the GUI standard is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com).

Comment: Also on the Mac TextWrangler and XCode.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck on Windows for this project, and would like to avoid a GUI. I really just need to create a report that shows where the differences in files are so that I can debug the code that is creating them.

Comment: install Rtools and you get diff

Comment: @mdsumner how exactly, using Rccp? I want access to the gnu::diff function within R.  I have Rtools installed on Windoze, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999090/

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to insert the output of the diffr function with the following code in a Rmarkdown :

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:
```

```
{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
library(diffr)

file1 <- tempfile()
writeLines("hello, world!\n", con = file1)
file2 <- tempfile()
writeLines(paste0("hello world?\nI don't get it\n", paste0(sample(letters, 65, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")), con = file2)

diffr(file1, file2, before = "f1", after = "f2")
```

Afterwards, we can visualize the html file.