# How to get the "diff" of two strings?

Tags: r, nlp, diff, git-diff

The base R function `diff` computes a first difference, useful for lagged data comparisons.

I am looking for the GNU `diff` function accessible in R:  https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

This function is useful for version control, but also useful in natural language processes to identify changes or edits between two similar text elements.  This is also an underlying engine of git and so on.

Ideally the function would be `gnudiff(text1,text2)` and if tied to `quanteda` or another library, that would be awesome.

How do I get the `diff` of two text elements?

Comment: What difference are you interested in? You could look at `stringdist` or `similiars`. Is it just a "diff" as in A not in B that you need? For the latter, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811878/show-difference-between-files-or-objects)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `diffObj()`

```
library(diffobj)
diffObj(text1, text2)
```